# How to preserve Fragment instance in backstack when using Navigation Component without using ViewModels?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there a way preserve my fragments instances so that they don't get recreates when coming back from another Fragment through navigation component?

I thought of saving the fragment's instance in a variable and using it if it's not null in onCreateView(), but it seems this is not advised can generate memory leaks.

It's my only option to refactor my app and use ViewModels in all my fragments?

Comment: The Fragments themselves _don't_ get destroyed (you'll note that `onDestroy()` is not called).

Comment: Understood, I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

When `Fragment` is recreated from back stack, first method which gets called is `onCreateView` while when `Fragment` is being created for first time, `onAttach` followed by `onCreate` is called.

So you can avoid reinitialization of variables using these one time invoked methods in order to preserve their previous states. But this is advisable for small use cases only. To preserve larger data sets, you should consider using `ViewModels` which are bound to fragment lifecycle and retains the data until fragment is detached & destroyed.

You can post your exact use case here if you need more help.

Comment: I think I will have to migrate to ViewModela since I would like more than on fragment to preserve it's instance. This fragment in particular is a recycler which presents a list of restaurants. (A delivery App)